# Blank screen when testing WebGL demo

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I've copied this from a demo. It is supposed to simply draw a cube on the screen but nothing appears. Originally I had it loading a OBJ with a texture, but that wasn't working so I decided to make it more simple by just drawing a cube. So far I know it runs through the animate function and render function, and I see the clear screen colour, but cannot get any objects to appear.

This is test.js:

```
var CubeTest = function(container) {

var scene, renderer;
var camera

var backgroundColour = 0xeeeeee;
var cube;

function init()
{
    //
    camera = new THREE.Camera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 350;

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create the Cube
    cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 ), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
    scene.add(cube);

    //
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(backgroundColour, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

//
function animate()
{
    render();
}

//
function render()
{
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

//
init();
this.animate = animate;

//
return this;
};
```

And this is the script section of test.html:

```
<script>
//
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var cube1 = new CubeTest(container);
cube1.animate();
</script>
```

Yes, there is a container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read through the guide for Three.js. It contains a simple example of how to do exactly what you're looking for, drawing a cube.

The guide can be found at the following location: http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

---

Live Example:
http://jsbin.com/suqojejiqihi/1/

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Edit

In your example, you are using `THREE.Camera` and passing it arguments that its not designed to work with. Have a look at the constructor for `THREE.Camera`:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/Camera.js

```
THREE.Camera = function () {

    THREE.Object3D.call( this );

    this.matrixWorldInverse = new THREE.Matrix4();
    this.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

};
```

Now lets compare this to the constructor for `THREE.PerspectiveCamera`:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js

```
THREE.PerspectiveCamera = function ( fov, aspect, near, far ) {

    THREE.Camera.call( this );

    this.fov = fov !== undefined ? fov : 50;
    this.aspect = aspect !== undefined ? aspect : 1;
    this.near = near !== undefined ? near : 0.1;
    this.far = far !== undefined ? far : 2000;

    this.updateProjectionMatrix();

};
```

Comment: What a good reply. Looking over it, it looks like I forgot to add a material, however, if I remove the material part on your code it still draws a cube. Is there something wrong with my javascript object or something wrong with the camera?

Comment: I would recommend using the PerspectiveCamera over the base Camera class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's weird because I copied that straight from example code. It works now, thanks :)